# Google form input into Spreadsheet

Tags: formula, spreadsheet, google-forms

Im using Google Forms to collect data into a sheet with existing formulas. Is it possible to lock existing data in the sheet, so its on the same row? Now, when a user submits the form, it puts the existing data a row down.

Thanks for helping

Tried to find a way to lock the data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet Name") {
    sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1,sh.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
    sh.getRange(2,1,1,e.values.length).setValues([e.values])
  }
}
```